# Theano : Pass iterating index of scan to the called function

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, theano.scan

Is it possible to pass the iterating index of scan to the function I am calling from scan?
For eg -

```
def step(x,i):
   # i is the current scan index. Use it for some conditional expressions

for i in range(0,10):
    step(x,i)
```

I want to do something similar using theano. Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is shown in the theano tutorials, for example [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html#computing-the-jacobian).

The first argument of the function is automatically taken from the `sequences` argument of scan, if provided.
For example, suppose you want to add to every element of a vector `x` its corresponding index.
You could do it with `theano.scan` like this:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dvector('x')
def step(idx, array):
    return array[idx] + idx
results, updates = theano.scan(fn=step,
                               sequences=T.arange(x.shape[0]),
                               non_sequences=[x])
f = theano.function([x], results)
f([1., 0., 2.13])
# array([ 1.  ,  1.  ,  4.13])
```

so basically: mind the order of the arguments of the function you give to `scan`, as they are passed in a specific order.
You can see exactly what order in the relevant [documentation page of scan](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#theano.scan).

Comment: thank you for the reply. That works! I next want to compare this idx variable to a 'int' variable and based on that return something. But, here idx is a tensor variable. Any clues on how can I do the comparison. Simply doing `if T.lt(idx,seqLen-1):` always returns true. May be it is comparing the first index value only everytime. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If it is not related to this problem you should open another question for it